# on the series $\sum {\sin(nz)\over n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone help me to show that $\sum {\sin(nz)\over n}$ diverges if 
$Im(z)\ne 0$?

Thank you

Comment: Check the Dirichlet test.

Comment: Expand the sine for a complex argument.